# Changing Project package name in AndroidManifest

Tags: android, mobile, cordova

I have a project which is running successfully.It is an hybrid Web application using phonegap where I have used Phonegap core functionality and as well as I have created my own plugins for some of  the functionalities. I just changed the package structure of my first activity class and the same in Android Manifest XML file. I am using command prompt to update the project and ant debug to make apk file .

APK has created successfully but when I installed it on the device and opening the project Some of the features are not working.

Comment: make sure you have updated the changed name in all activity's package statement also and in manifest and R.java

Comment: yes  I have updated all the files.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have changed package name in all other packages as well, hint: see if you missed changing package name in any of file which whose functionality is missing in app.